# Unite two numerical columns into one in R

Tags: r

I have a df1

```
X          Y    
CA23-11    002 0033
CA67-55    011 0245
```

I would like to create df2

```
Z
CA2311-2-33
CA6755-11-245
```

My code to do this is
df2 <- df %>% unite(Z, X:Y, remove = "0", sep="-")
and my error is: Error in if(remove) { : argument in not interpertable as logical

Any assistance in this would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: `remove` takes a logical i.e. TRUE/FALSE instead of character "0" i.e. you need `unite(Z, X:Y, remove = FALSE, sep = '-')`. this will return the original columns as well, if you use `remove = TRUE`, it removes X, Y columns

Comment: Thank you for the correction.  However that code gives me an output of CA23-11-002 0033.  I am wondering how to get rid of the "-" in the first column and the 0's in the second column with adding "-" to combine the numbers from the 2nd column only

Comment: Please check the solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `base R` to return the expected output.  Read the 'Y' column with `read.table` so that it automatically reads into `numeric` columns splitting at the whitespace, `cbind` with `-` removed 'X' column, change the `format` with `sprintf`

```
data.frame(Z = do.call(sprintf, c(fmt = '%s-%d-%d', 
      cbind(sub("-", "", df1$X), 
     read.table(text = df1$Y, header = FALSE)))))
```

-ouptut

```
          Z
1   CA2311-2-33
2 CA6755-11-245
```

---

Or using [`tidyverse`](https://www.tidyverse.org/)

1. We [`separate`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tidyr/versions/1.1.3/topics/separate) the 'Y' by splitting at space, and `convert` the type to `numeric`
2. Remove the `-` in 'X' - [`str_remove`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringr/versions/1.4.0/topics/str_remove)
3. Then [`unite`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tidyr/versions/0.8.3/topics/unite) the 3 columns together

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>% 
   separate(Y, into = c("Y1", "Y2"), convert = TRUE) %>%
   mutate(X = str_remove(X, '-')) %>% 
   unite(Z, X, Y1, Y2, sep= '-')
              Z
1   CA2311-2-33
2 CA6755-11-245
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(X = c("CA23-11", "CA67-55"), Y = c("002 0033", 
"011 0245")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution using built-in functions:

```
df2 <- data.frame(Z = paste0(sub("-", "", df1$X), gsub("^0*| 0*", "-", df1$Y)))
df2
#               Z
# 1   CA2311-2-33
# 2 CA6755-11-245
```